# Read line from stdin until EOF and print the text after test for first character

Tags: c, stdin

<strike>I wanr interactive</strike>(I want to) read a line from standard input until EOF but after each line I want to print if the line first character is `'+'` then print `"OK"` else print `"NOT OK"`.  I tried this code but this prints `"NOT OK"` even if the line I input has a first character equal to `'+'`.

```
int main()
{
    #define BUF_SIZE 1024
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    size_t contentSize = 1;
    /* Preallocate space.  We could just allocate one char here,
    but that wouldn't be efficient. */
    char *content = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUF_SIZE);
    if(content == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate content");
        exit(1);
    }
    content[0] = '\0'; // make null-terminated
    while(fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin))
    {
        char *old = content;
        contentSize += strlen(buffer);
        content = realloc(content, contentSize);
        if(content == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to reallocate content");
            free(old);
            exit(2);
        }
        strcat(content, buffer);
        if (content[0]== '+')  {
            printf("OK\n");
        } else {
            printf("NOT OK\n");
        }
    }

    if(ferror(stdin))
    {
        free(content);
        perror("Error reading from stdin.");
        exit(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is? BTW, is your `.` key broken?

Comment: yes this code print NOT OK even if the first character in contetn is '+'

Comment: OT: Can you make sure that no input line is longer then 1023 `char`s?

Comment: not i am not sure, maybe the all code is bad

Comment: You want to handle reading input and interpreting input separately.

Comment: 1st read until you have new-line, then parse its content.

Comment: using fgets? But I must input until eof

Comment: To read a _line_, reading should stop if 1) `'\n'` is read, 2) End-of-file occurs, or 3) Input error occurs.  This code is missing #1 if the line is longer than 1023.  Is that your intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating the buffer to the content

```
strcat(content, buffer);
```

So for the 1st input , suppose "abc" `content` will be **abc** and it will print NOT OK . 
For the 2nd input, suppose "+xyz" `content` will be **abc+xyz** so the value of `content[0]` will always be **"a"** and hence it will always print NOT OK.

Similarly if your 1st input is "+abc" , then it will always print OK for all the inputs.

Use strcpy instead of strcat

```
strcpy(content, buffer);
```

Comment: i comment the line `content[0] = '\0';` either thi script pritn after any input line NOT OK even if first charcter is +

Comment: sorry no need to comment this. I have edited my comment. Execute and confirm this

Answer (score 2):

To read a *line* via `fgets()`, better to handle this as a stand-alone function [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149185/read-line-from-stdin-until-eof-and-print-the-text-after-test-for-first-string#comment69502091_41149185)

Following suggested code is similar to OP's.  A key difference is testing if `fgets(buffer)` read a `'\n'`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 10

char *readline_mardon(void) {
  char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
  size_t contentSize = 1;
  char *content = malloc(contentSize);
  if (content == NULL) {
    perror("Failed to allocate content");
    exit(1);
  }
  content[0] = '\0'; // make null-terminated
  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
    size_t buffer_length = strlen(buffer);

    // more idiomatic code
    // Assign `content` after successful allocation detected
    size_t contentSize_new = contentSize + buffer_length;
    printf("%zu <%s>\n", buffer_length, buffer);
    char *content_new = realloc(content, contentSize_new);
    if (content_new == NULL) {
      perror("Failed to reallocate content");
      free(content);
      exit(2);
    }

    // memcpy faster than strcat as the end of the first part is known
    memcpy(content_new + contentSize - 1, buffer, buffer_length + 1);

    content = content_new;
    contentSize = contentSize_new;

    // look for \n
    if (buffer_length > 0 && buffer[buffer_length - 1] == '\n') {
      break;
    }
  }
  return content;
}
```

Usage

```
char *s;
while((s = readline_mardon()) != NULL) {
  if (s[0]== '+')  {
    printf("OK\n");
  } else {
    printf("NOT OK\n");
  }
  free(s);
}
```

Additional code could return `NULL` if *nothing* was read or an input error occurred.

Comment: I try this but even line has first letter + the NOT OK is printing and when input line is under 10 char i obtain error in realloc